# Normalization when datasets are from different sources

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning

I am working on object detection in a medical context, and I am currently applying convolutional neural networks through Caffe. I first train a binary classifier on patches extracted from the images, and then convert this model into a fully convolutional network to detect and localize the objects.

This is working OK, however, I believe that one of my main challenges is the dataset and its normalization. My training/validation set comes from two different sources (cameras), while the testing set comes from a third source. Thus I don't want the model to be sensitive to variance in brightness and color etc. In addition, my training dataset is not very large.

My idea is to normalization and data augmentation to improve my model, but I have not yet found a good approach.

1. Do you have hints on or resources with possible approaches?
2. Is data augmentation by adding a random scalar to the whole image OK? (changing the brightness)
3. Should I consider changing the gamma?
4. Should I do mean subtraction separately on the training and testing sets?
5. Is CLAHE or other histogram normalization algorithms a good approach? (my images are RGB)

Comment: This depends a lot in your data, and with no further knowledge of it, is quite difficult to say. One thing you can do and usually works, is to [*standarize*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) your data. For each individual dataset (image or volume), subtract to all pixels the mean of the image and divide it by the global standard deviation of the image. This way all your images will have mean 0 and standard deviation of 1. Another kind of normalization is the [*feature scaling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) where you put each of your images in `[0, 1]` range.

Comment: Have you tried merging all of your data sets, shuffling them and then doing the train/test split? That might help your model learn to handle all cases you describe.

Comment: @imaluengo: Thanks, I realize it depends a lot on my data, so I'm mostly looking for hints and tips on possible things to try. I am currently subtracting from each pixel the mean of the whole dataset, but I could try subtracting the image mean from each pixel of each image instead. When you divide by the standard deviation, would you do this channel-wise?

Comment: @IVlad: I do shuffle my training set (and split off a validation set), the testing set is however provided separately, and I cannot mix it in.

Comment: @burk you substract the mean and divide it by std *image-wise* (not dataset-wise). And answering to the second question, it would be channelwise. Given a image `I` that can be splitted in 3 `R, G, B` images, you apply channel-wise `R = (R - mean(R)) / std(R)` (the same for B and G) and merge the 3 back to a *standarized* 3 channel image.

Comment: @IVlad: Hmm, OK. I thought it was normal to subtract the mean across the feature dimension (pixel), to normalize each feature, as opposed to normalizing across each sample? Also, this [tutorial](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Data_Preprocessing#Per-example_mean_subtraction) warns against subtracting the mean of each channel. Any input on how to understand this, or any good resources?

Comment: @burk I think you mistagged me, but you and imaluengo seem to be talking about the same thing. You want to do what "Feature Standardization" describes in the tutorial you linked to.

Comment: Also, for "Should I do mean subtraction separately on the training and testing sets?", I'm not sure what you mean. You should do the normalization on your training set and save the values (mean and stdev). Then use the saved mean and stdev to normalize your test set at test time. For the other questions, you should probably test and see what gives the best results.

Comment: @IVlad: Ah, sorry for the mistagging, but thanks for the answer. As for feature standardization, you normally divide by the std of a _dimension_ (e.g. the std of a pixel position across all images?) while imaluengo suggests dividing by the std of a "sample" (one image). Or have I misunderstood? Also, what I meant with doing the subtraction separately was possibly calculating a different mean over the test set, since this set is from a different source (camera) and possibly has a different mean. But yeah, I'll try different approaches.

Comment: Well, as far as I know, you should divide by the std of a dimension. I'm not sure if things are different regarding image processing however. Your algorithm should still work with images from different cameras if you apply the right preprocessing steps. The mean of the test set will be slightly different anyway, but the idea is that if you do everything right, it won't matter too much.